# Update statement error in java (SQL error or missing database (near "credits": syntax error))

Tags: java, sqlite

I am trying to update data but (SQL error or missing database (near "credits": syntax error) occured, i have checked the code meticulously but to no avail and furthermore the code is of the similar structure to the one that i found online for sqlite java tutorial.

`String sql = "UPDATE GPAdatabase SET yrandsem = ? , " + " module = ? " + " credits = ? " + " grade = ? " + "WHERE id = ?";`

Comment: Could you state the structure of your database?

Comment: id , yrandsem , module , credits & grade

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are forgetting `,`:

```
String sql = "UPDATE GPAdatabase SET yrandsem = ?, " + "module = ?, " + " credits = ?, " + "grade = ? " + "WHERE id = ?";
```